# Is there a way to export an array so that each its value could be imported into another js file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I was wondering if it's possible to somehow make array/object's children to be exportable into another `.js` files

Let's say, I have a file `a.js` with this code:

```
const vector = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
export default vector;
```

Array's elements may be functions, collections, whatever...

Is there a way I could do the following in my file `b.js`?

```
import {c} from './a.js';
// do something with c
```

Comment: First off what is `const vector = [a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'];`?  Perhaps you meant: `const vector = {a: 'a', b: 'b', c: 'c'};`?

Comment: @jfriend00, Sorry, my fault... I fixed it

Comment: I reopened, now that you've made the question a legit array.  You can export an array, but array elements are indexed by number, not by value.

Comment: I appreciate this

Answer (score 0):

If you do:

```
const vector = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
export default vector;
```

Then, when you `import`, you have to reference the array element by number or use some other array method on it.  Arrays are not indexed by value, they are accessed by their index.

```
import vector from '/a.js';
console.log(vector[2]);            // 'c'
console.log(vector.indexOf('c'));  // 2
```

> Is there a way I could do the following in my file b.js?  `import {c} from './a.js';`.

No.  What you exported has no `c` property.  In fact, the array you exported has no custom properties at all, just the array elements which are accessed like any array element would be.